# Send hidden value along with drop down form data?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to send a hidden value based on what option a user selects in a drop down menu.
Though at the moment it requires the submit button to be pressed twice.

Is there any way I can fix this or maybe a different method I should use?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<form name="input" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <select name="myValue" value="">
                <option value="300"<?php if ($_GET['myValue']==300) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>First Option</option>
                <option value="800"<?php if ($_GET['myValue']==800) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Second Option</option>
                </select>

<?php if ($_GET['myValue']==300) {echo "<input type='hidden' name='hiddenValue' id='hiddenValue' value='123456'><br />"; } ?>
<?php if ($_GET['myValue']==800) {echo "<input type='hidden' name='hiddenValue' id='hiddenValue' value='987456'><br />"; } ?>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<?php
echo "myValue: " . $_GET['myValue'];
echo "<br />";
echo "hiddenValue: " . $_GET['hiddenValue'];
?>
```

Comment: why dont you have the hidden values in the option values like `<option value="123456"<?php if ($_GET['myValue']==300) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>First Option</option>`

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am understanding your question correctly but, I need both values to be sent.

So if the first option is chosen I need myValue which is 300 and the hiddenValue which is 123456.

Comment: Just so you know why this is happening: You are using a `$_GET` value to populate the `hiddenValue` field. This means that `hiddenValue` will not have a value until the form is submitted. Since you then display the value of `$_GET['hiddenValue']`, you will not have anything displayed here until you submit with a value in `hiddenValue`. So you must submit once to populate `hiddenValue`, and then again to populate your `echo` statement.

Comment: @PatrickQ Ya that is what I was thinking was happening. But I can't think of any other way to have the hidden value change based on what option is selected by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add the hidden value in the php script after you press submit. IfOption A is selected, $hiddenvalue = X. Else, if Option B is selected, $hiddenvalue = y.

```
<?php

  $selection = $_GET['myValue'];

  if ($selection == 1) {
     $hidden = "x";
  } elseif ($selection == 2) {
     $hidden = "y";
  }

  echo $selection;
  echo "<br />";
  echo $hidden;

?>
```

Comment: @DecodedMonkey and if you want to send those hidden values without again submitting the form then after the echo $hidden make one curl post request.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use POST method instead of GET in form ,

```
<?php
echo "myValue: " . $_POST['myValue'];
echo "<br />";
echo "hiddenValue: " . $_POST['hiddenValue'];
?>
```

Comment: That would make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the hidden value as value for options:

here is what i would suggest:

```
<form name="input" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <select name="myValue" value="">
                <option value="123456"<?php if ($_GET['myValue']==300) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>First Option</option>
                <option value="987456"<?php if ($_GET['myValue']==800) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Second Option</option>
                </select>    
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

or use a javascript function and make an ajax call if you cannot change the `option` values

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to get the value of the dropdown box and append a hidden box just before submitting the form based on what the user selected on the dropdown?

Maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7sXXy/

```
formSubmit() {
  var select = $("#select");
  if(select.val() == 300) {
   select.after("<input type='hidden'/ name='hidden' value='1'/>");
  }else{
   select.after("<input type='hidden'/ name='hidden' value='2'/>");   
  }
  return true;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you're ultimately wanting to do with this data, the best I can do is meet this specific use-case. Assuming that you probably want to do something a bit more complex, you'll have to make some modifications.

```
<form name="input" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <select name="myValue" value="">
                <option value="300"<?php if ($_GET['myValue']==300) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>First Option</option>
                <option value="800"<?php if ($_GET['myValue']==800) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Second Option</option>
                </select>


<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<?php
$myValue = $_GET['myValue'];
echo "myValue: " . $myValue;
echo "<br />";
echo "hiddenValue: " . ($myValue == 300 ? 123456 : ($myValue == 800 ? 987456 : ''));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a javascript function to read out the selected option on submit and fill the hidden field with it

```
<script>
function fillhiddenformfield(formobj)
{
    // the select element
    var se = formobj.myValue;

    // the selected value 
    var sv = se.options[se.selectedIndex].value;

    // set the hidden field
    formobj.hiddenValue.value = sv;

    // return true to submit the form
    return true;
}
</script>   

<? // action is obsolete here as your are sending to this script ?> 
<form name="input"  method="get" onsubmit="fillhiddenformfield(this)">
            <select name="myValue" value="">
            <option value="300"<?php if ($_GET['myValue']==300) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>First Option</option>
            <option value="800"<?php if ($_GET['myValue']==800) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Second Option</option>
            </select>
 <input type='hidden' name='hiddenValue' id='hiddenValue'>
```